# How do I change accessibility on an accessor using CodeDom?

Tags: c#, codedom, accessor

In C#, you can have more restrictive accessors on the accessors of a property like this:

```
public List<String> Name { get; protected set; }
```

How can I accomplish this when generating code using CodeDom?

Comment: Why to do that? It is not Ruby, it is C#.

Comment: Why do what? Generate code or use different accessibility modifiers?

Comment: Sorry guys, I though the question was *how to change access modifier*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeDom doesn't directly support this.  CodeDom dates from an era when C# and Visual Basic didn't support different accessibility on the get and set method, and hasn't been updated to support the new functionality.  You will probably need to use a CodeSnippetTypeMember (though with a bit of ingenuity you could still use CodeDom to generate the getter and setter bodies).