# How do achieve Asymmetric Accessor Accessibility using CodeDom?

Tags: c#, codedom

How can I achieve [Asymmetric Accessor Accessibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75e8y5dd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) using `CodeDOM`;

```
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return name;
    }
    protected set
    {
        name = value;
    }
}
```

I found a duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414510/c-how-do-i-change-accessibility-on-an-accessor-using-codedom) but, now C# 5.0 and .NET framework 4.5 in the run. Is it impossible now either?

By this code;

```
//Declare a property in target class and set attributes of the property
                CodeMemberProperty newPropertyGetter = new CodeMemberProperty();
                newPropertyGetter.Attributes = (MemberAttributes)Enum.Parse(typeof(MemberAttributes), visibilityGetter) | MemberAttributes.Final;
                newPropertyGetter.Name = propName;
                newPropertyGetter.Type = new CodeTypeReference(propType);
                newPropertyGetter.HasGet = needGet;


                CodeMemberProperty newPropertySetter = new CodeMemberProperty();
                newPropertySetter.Attributes = (MemberAttributes)Enum.Parse(typeof(MemberAttributes), visibilitySetter) | MemberAttributes.Final;
                newPropertySetter.Name = propName;
                newPropertySetter.Type = new CodeTypeReference(propType);
                newPropertySetter.HasSet = needSet;
```

I can get like this;

```
public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }        
    }

public string Name
    {        
        protected set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }
```

Is it valid? Or is it not a good practice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: How do I change accessibility on an accessor using CodeDom?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414510/c-how-do-i-change-accessibility-on-an-accessor-using-codedom)

Comment: As far as I'm aware, CodeDOM wasn't changed in any way in .Net 4.5. And about that code, have you tried to compile it? (I think you'll find that it's actually not valid.)

Comment: @svick It is a duplicate. I've stated it. I thought the new framework might have something. Is my implementation OK?

Comment: @svick validity is my concern too. But, it wont compiles either.

Comment: Is there any possibility to achieve Asymmetric Accessor Accessibility other than CodeDOM?